# Xamarin.Forms How to display progress indicator while sound recording/playback takes place

Tags: xamarin.forms, progress-bar, audio-recording

I would like to display a progress indicator while recording sound in my app.
The amount of time allocated for the recording is predefined. I set that up in code, lets say 10 seconds maximum recording time, but the user can stop the recording in less time, and of course he progress indicator would stop and reset.

I have been trying to make it work right could you please offer some guidance.
Note: I am using the NateRickard AudioRecorder nuget package.

```
if (!recorder.IsRecording)
                {
                    buttonRecord.IsEnabled = false;
                    buttonPlay.IsEnabled = false;

                    DependencyService.Get<IAudioService>().PrepareRecording();

                    // start recording
                    var recordTask = await recorder.StartRecording();

                    // set up progress bar
                    //progressBarRecordTime.Progress = 1.0;
                    //await progressBarRecordTime.ProgressTo(1.0, 10000, Easing.Linear);

                    buttonRecord.Text = "Stop Recording";
                    buttonRecord.IsEnabled = true;

                    // get the recorded file
                    var recordedAudioFile = await recordTask;                       

                    buttonRecord.Text = "Record";
                    buttonPlay.IsEnabled = true;

                    if (recordedAudioFile != null)
                    {
                        var recordingFileDestinationPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, AppConstants.CUSTOM_ALERT_FILENAME);

                        if (File.Exists(recordingFileDestinationPath))
                        {
                            File.Delete(recordingFileDestinationPath);
                        }

                        File.Copy(recordedAudioFile, recordingFileDestinationPath);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Place an *ActivityIndicator* (name it **ind**) in your xaml code (view)

At the top of your code above:

```
        ind.IsRunning = true;
        //
        if (!recorder.IsRecording)
        //
```

when you are done, add this below your code

```
//
        }

        File.Copy(recordedAudioFile, recordingFileDestinationPath);
    }
}
ind.IsRunning = false;
```